# how can I use readyonstatechange function to return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, onreadystatechange

I want to use javascript request xmlhttp to trigger java action 
so I used the following function as function call and return data, but can't return response cause I write return statement in other inner function like that.

```
function loadXMLDoc(action,request)
{
var act = action+".action"+request;
console.log("load action");
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
     else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        return JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);            

    }
    else{

    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET",act,true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

caller function......

```
var data = loadXMLDoc("load","?reuqest=request");
```

where should I write return and how could I access returned data ?

Comment: Since you have a jquery tag I would suggest looking into using query for your ajax call.  It will simplify your life.

Comment: @HeadCode Could I use $.ajax() for this ???

Comment: I added an another answer below, in case you wanted to take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to take a callback:

```
function loadXMLDoc(action,request, callback)
```

Pass a callback to your `loadXMLDoc` as in

```
loadXMLDoc("load","?reuqest=request", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

and call the callback in your success:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    callback(xmlhttp.responseText);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the ".action" in your URL, but a Jquery answer could look like this

```
function loadXML(url, cb){
    $.get(url, function(data){
        cb(data);
    });
}

function myFunc(data){
    alert(data);
}

loadXML("http://www.example.com/test.xml", myFunc);
```